# Why is ListView getChildAt working only upto certain index?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have a `ListView` with `CheckBox` and `TextView`. I am trying to find `CheckBox` using index. In my current testscenario I have 16 items in `ListView`. Following code works until index 5 and gives `IllegalStateException` after that. Why is that happening? **How can I get `CheckBox` of all indices?** I believe it has something to do with `Layout` only representing visible rows. But even when I scroll down, index 0 works and indices bigger than 5 don't. `ListView` is private attribute within the class. Code:

```
public void inform(View v) {            
            TextView tv;
            CheckBox cb;
            String s = "";
            int nrItems = lv.getCount();
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) lv.getChildAt(6);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(layout.getChildCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cb = (CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Boolean.toString(cb.isChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: it works only for the pooled views

Comment: How do I get all indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the views that are visible are actually there. If you scroll down so you see row 6 till 10 for example then `getChildAt(0);` is actually row 6 because it is the first view that is actually there

EDIT:
What you probably try to do is getten the isChecked() values of all checkboxes. The thing is there are never more checkboxes than visible on the screen. So 'all checkboxes' is never all 16.

The checkbox itself should only be a representation  of some data. You shouldn't rely on the fact on `isChecked` to do something. You should keep a seperate list or array of boolean values that represent whether the checkbox is checked. This is also useful when reusing rows which I guess you don't do.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. Do you know how to get all `CheckBox`s?

Answer (score 1):

Use ListView with your own adapter.
Example:

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<Item> mData ; // Don't forget to instantiate this



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked){
    for(Item item : mData){
        item.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Some example. Create or inflate view here
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = new CheckBox(parent.getContext());
    convertView.isChecked(mData.isChecked);

    return convertView ;
}
}
```

**Updated**

Point is you need to change Data and not views directly. After calling notofyDataSetChanged() for adapter all views will be changed automatically.

Comment: how do you sync checkbox values with list in the activity?

Comment: Thanks. But what I wanted to do was change the list (the list itself, not the list in adapter) given to adapter automatically when I check a checkbox in listview.